# Become a sudoer user with password associated with host information

Tags: ansible

I need to access a few servers whose passwords are built using servers hostname, so, let's suppose hostname is: fancyHost and password prefix is "principio", then the sudoer user's (contoso-r in this example) password is going to be: "principiofancyHost". This in order to assign a new password to each host.

Problem is I managed to connect and stablish a custom password as a variable, and scalate to sudoer, but seems like ansible become_pass is not meant to be manipulated inside the task, which makes difficult to concatenate the prefix with the hostname.

---

```
   - hosts: test
     vars:
     prefix: "principio"
     ansible_become_pass: “hardToGuessPassword123”

     tasks:
     - name: getting current server hostname
     command: hostname
     register: hostname

     - name: getting current user name
     command: whoami
     register: current_username

     - name: print current server hostname
     debug:
       msg: "Current user: {{current_username.stdout}} |||  Hostname is: {{ hostname.stdout}} ||| Password should be: {{ prefix + hostname.stdout}}"

     - name: changing contoso-r' s  password
     become: True
     become_user: contoso-r
     become_method: su
     user:
       name: contoso-r
       password: "{{ (prefix + hostname.stdout) | password_hash('sha512') }}"
       state: present
       shell: /bin/bash
       system: no
       createhome: no
```

How could I set a custom password relative to each host instead a global become_pass or ansible_become_pass?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Post the error message, if any, and fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: there's no error messages, I just need to use a different password for each server, so, I can't use a "global" var as become_pass, because it would only work in just one server, I need to "modify" the become_pass according to the hostname. Thanks!

Comment: Use [Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) to "modify" the become_pass according to the hostname.

Comment: But it would mean that I have to feed the inventory file rather than using ansible to “form” the password according to those two variables: prefix and hostname

Answer (score 0):

You stated:

> I managed to connect ... and escalate to sudoer, ...

It's not necessary to "*become_user: contoso-r*" when "*changing contoso-r' s  password*".

```
- name: changing contoso-r' s  password
  user:
    name: contoso-r
    password: "{{ (prefix + hostname.stdout) | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

Comment: Vladimir, the only user with privileges is contoso-r, I need to scalate to that user, or not?

Comment: There is *ansible_become_pass* set in the play. If the *ansible_become_user* is contoso-r ,and the password for this user is changed, then the play can't proceed with the *ansible_become_pass*.

Comment: In that case, just have the change password task be the last task in that play, then start a new play with the new password.

Comment: The only task I need to do is to gather the hostname, and if contoso-r exists, then escalate using the prefix variable concatenated with hostname as the root (contoso-r) and change it’s password. My playbook is already doing it if I provide the password, which seems unnecessary due it is easily formed by that concatenation. Problem is I haven’t managed to change the become password WITHIN the task according each host.